# How to delete rows in python pandas DataFrame using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pattern:

```
patternDel = "( \\((MoM|QoQ)\\))";
```

And I want to delete all rows in pandas dataframe where column `df['Event Name']` matches this pattern. Which is the best way to do it?  There are more than 100k rows in dataframe.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you import columns with that string, they will be converted to `"( \((MoM|QoQ)\))"` unless they are raw strings. It would be helpful to include a sample of the data in order to get the best answer.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[str.contains()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) returns a Series of booleans that we can use to index our frame

```
patternDel = "( \\((MoM|QoQ)\\))"
filter = df['Event Name'].str.contains(patternDel)
```

I tend to keep the things we want as opposed to delete rows.  Since filter represents things we want to delete we use `~` to get all the rows that don't match and keep them

```
df = df[~filter]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  Probably shouldn't use the keyword "filter" as a variable name though, just to avoid confusion.